# How to remove elements of array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

Is it possible to remove **multiple** elements from an array? 
Before removing elements Array1 is :

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

Array2 that contains some elements I wish to remove:

```
{1,4}
```

And I want to get:

```
 {2,3}
```

How to operate?

Comment: You can remove individual elements using `array_remove()` but unless you install the [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) module you can't easily remove one array from another

Comment: for small amount of values you can use multiple time `array_remove`; for more you can looping with `array_remove`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two arrays and pick only the non matching elements In postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533029/how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-pick-only-the-non-matching-elements-in-postgres)

Answer (score 22):

Use `unnest()` with `array_agg()`, e.g.:

```
with cte(array1, array2) as (
    values (array[1,2,3,4], array[1,4])
    )
select array_agg(elem)
from cte, unnest(array1) elem
where elem <> all(array2);

 array_agg 
-----------
 {2,3}
(1 row)
```

If you often need this functionality, define the simple function:

```
create or replace function array_diff(array1 anyarray, array2 anyarray)
returns anyarray language sql immutable as $$
    select coalesce(array_agg(elem), '{}')
    from unnest(array1) elem
    where elem <> all(array2)
$$;
```

You can use the function for any array, not only `int[]`:

```
select array_diff(array['a','b','c','d'], array['a','d']);

 array_diff 
------------
 {b,c}
(1 row)
```

Comment: This requirement seems like something trivial, something very common, why is there no native function for this, is anything planned for this ?

Comment: Well, there is no *native* function [even in python.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4211209/1995738) On the other hand, there is nothing to prevent you from creating the function in your database and treating it as native.

Comment: How does this compare to the following variant: `select array(select unnest(:arr1) except select unnest(:arr2));`. I suppose your variant it is a bit better on large arrays because it does less unnesting ?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy - yes, the variant in the answer should be faster (maybe not so much).

Comment: What does `all()` do in this case?

Comment: @Dex - [Row and Array Comparisons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.17)

Answer (score 18):

With some help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533029/how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-pick-only-the-non-matching-elements-in-postgres):

```
select array_agg(elements) from 
   (select unnest('{1,2,3,4}'::int[]) 
except 
   select unnest('{1,4}'::int[])) t (elements)
```

Result:

```
{2,3}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution (and others on this page) are close, but are not sufficient. In some cases, they can alter the array order. E.g., in this answer, try replacing `{1,4}` above with `{2,4}`. The result is `{3,1}`.

Answer (score 12):

With the  [intarray extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html), you can simply use `-`:

```
select '{1,2,3,4}'::int[] - '{1,4}'::int[]
```

Result:

```
{2,3}
```

[Online demonstration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9374/0)

You'll need to [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html) the intarray extension if you didn't already. It adds many convenient functions and operators if you're dealing with arrays of integers.

Comment: You need the `intarray` extension for that to work: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html

Comment: "just use `-`" and a need for installing an extension is contradictory, isn't it?

Comment: @OndřejŽelazko You're right. Reworded that. But well, when dealing with such arrays, this should be standard in your pg installation...

Answer (score 9):

This answer is the simplest I think:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535089/673187

```
SELECT array(SELECT unnest(:array1) EXCEPT SELECT unnest(:array2));
```

so you can easily use it in an `UPDATE` command, when you need to remove some elements from an array column:

```
UPDATE table1 SET array1_column=(SELECT array(SELECT unnest(array1_column) EXCEPT SELECT unnest('{2, 3}'::int[])));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function for when you are dealing with bigint/int8 numbers and want to maintain order:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION arr_subtract(int8[], int8[])
  RETURNS int8[] AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT a
    FROM   unnest($1) WITH ORDINALITY x(a, ord)
    WHERE  a <> ALL ($2)
    ORDER  BY ord
    );
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

I got this solution from the following answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8584080/1544473

Answer (score 0):

User array re-dimension annotation

```
array[<start index>:<end index>] 

WITH t(stack, dim) as (
  VALUES(ARRAY[1,2,3,4], ARRAY[1,4])
) SELECT stack[dim[1]+1:dim[2]-1] FROM t
```