# Array difference in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have two arrays `[1,2,3,4,7,6]` and `[2,3,7]` in PostgreSQL which may have common elements. What I am trying to do is to exclude from the first array all the elements that are present in the second. 
So far I have achieved the following:

```
SELECT array
  (SELECT unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6])
   EXCEPT SELECT unnest(array[2, 3, 7]));
```

However, the ordering is not correct as the result is `{4,6,1}` instead of the desired `{1,4,6}`.
How can I fix this ?

---

I finally created a custom function with the following definition (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917905/how-to-remove-elements-of-array-in-postgresql)) which resolved my issue:

```
create or replace function array_diff(array1 anyarray, array2 anyarray)
returns anyarray language sql immutable as $$
    select coalesce(array_agg(elem), '{}')
    from unnest(array1) elem
    where elem <> all(array2)
$$;
```

Comment: You could install the [intarray](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) extension which offers an operator for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use `ORDINALITY` option of `UNNEST` and put an `ORDER BY` in the `array_agg` function while converting it back to array. `NOT EXISTS` is preferred over except to make it simpler.

```
SELECT array_agg(e order by id) 
   FROM unnest( array[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6] ) with ordinality as s1(e,id)
    WHERE not exists 
   (
     SELECT 1 FROM unnest(array[2, 3, 7]) as s2(e)
      where s2.e = s1.e
    )
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=af13097c6a86ffeebf2f0f91b920b8c4)

Comment: I will accept the answer since it resolves the initial question. However, I ended up creating a custom function which computes the "difference" of two arrays, the definition of which I have added in the initial question.

Answer (score -2):

Postgres is unfortunately lacking this functionality. In my case, what I really needed to do was to detect cases where the array difference was not empty. In that specific case you can do that with the `@>` operator which means "Does the first array contain the second?"

```
ARRAY[1,4,3] @> ARRAY[3,1,3] → t
```

See [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)