# SQL difference between array values of current row with previous row

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following table

| Date | SKUs |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | A, B, C |
| 2022-02-02 | B, C, D |
| 2022-02-03 | C, D, E |
| 2022-02-04 | C, D |
| 2022-02-05 | G, H |

Now I need to find the difference b/w SKUs of current date with previous date (something like lag function in Postgres)

| Date | SKUs | SKU Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | A, B, C |  |
| 2022-02-02 | B, C, D | D |
| 2022-02-03 | C, D, E | E |
| 2022-02-04 | C, D |  |
| 2022-02-05 | G, H | G, H |

`SKUs` column is of array type

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: 'something like lag function in Postgres)' - there is a lag function in mysql version 8 or above so what version are you on?

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm on Postgresql 9.x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array difference in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304197/array-difference-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

```
with SKU as 
(
select Dates,trim(a.value) as SKUs from SKUs s
cross apply string_split(s.SKUs,',') a
),
SKU_Diff as
(
SELECT dates, SKU_Diff FROM (SELECT Dates,STRING_AGG(SKUs,', ') as SKU_Diff, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY dates) AS rn 
FROM SKU s
WHERE s.SKUs not in (SELECT s1.skus FROM SKU s1 WHERE s.dates = dateadd(day,1,s1.dates))
GROUP BY dates) as a WHERE rn > 1
)
SELECT  s.Dates,SKUs,isnull(SKU_Diff,'') as SKU_Diff 
FROM SKUs s
left join SKU_Diff sd on s.dates = sd.dates;
```