# PostgreSQL : check if value is in 2 columns and remove it from one of them

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have two columns `ind` and `tar` that both contain arrays.

```python
 ind      tar
{10}      {10}
{6}       {5,6}
{4,5,6}   {5,6}
{5,6}     {5,6}
{7,8}     {11}
{11}      {5,6,7}
{11}      {8}
{9,10}    {6}
```

I want to find if one value exists in both arrays, and if that's true, I want to keep it only at column `ind`. For example, at the first row I have the value 10 in both columns. I want to end up with this value only in column `ind` and leave column `tar` empty. This is the expected result:

```python
 ind      tar      
{10}      
{6}       {5}
{4,5,6}   
{5,6}     
{7,8}     {11}
{11}      {5,6,7}
{11}      {8}
{9,10}    {6}
```

How can I do that in PostgreSQL?

So far I only managed to find the common elements, but I don't know how to continue with keeping them only at `ind` column and remove them from `tar` column.

```html
with t1 as (
select distinct ind, tar
from table_1
join table_2 using (id) 
limit 50
),
t2 as (
select ind & tar as common_el, ind , tar 
from t1
)
select *
from t2
```

which results into this:

```python
   common_el   ind        tar
    {10}      {10}       {10}
    {6}       {6}       {5,6}
    {5,6}     {4,5,6}   {5,6}
    {5,6}     {5,6}     {5,6}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` operator you are using is from the [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) module which also allows you to use `-` to remove elements in one array from another.

For eg.

```sql
select
    ind,
    tar,
    ind & tar as common_el,
    tar - (ind & tar) as  new_tar
from
    table_1
```

| ind | tar | common_el | new_tar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {10} | {10} | {10} | {} |
| {6} | {5,6} | {6} | {5} |
| {4,5,6} | {5,6} | {5,6} | {} |
| {5,6} | {5,6} | {5,6} | {} |
| {7,8} | {11} | {} | {11} |
| {11} | {5,6,7} | {} | {5,6,7} |
| {11} | {8} | {} | {8} |
| {9,10} | {6} | {} | {6} |

or simpler

```sql
select
    ind,
    tar,
    ind & tar as common_el,
    tar - ind as  new_tar
from
    table_1
```

[View working demo db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=67040b9067f1a39446c06ac58cd87398)

***Edit 1**: For non [`intarray`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/intarray.html) module users.*

Using [`UNNEST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html) to transform the array into multiple rows  this can be solved with multiple sql approaches to identify where elements of 1 set is not in another eg.

```sql
select
    ind,
    array(
        select t1.val from unnest(tar) t1(val)
        where t1.val not in (
             select val from unnest(ind) i1(val)
        )
    ) as  new_tar
from
    table_1
```

| ind | new_tar |
| --- | --- |
| {10} | {} |
| {6} | {5} |
| {4,5,6} | {} |
| {5,6} | {} |
| {7,8} | {11} |
| {11} | {5,6,7} |
| {11} | {8} |
| {9,10} | {6} |

[View working demo on db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d2c1525ba78f66ac46e4a7e9e61b1cdd)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=767e370843d1676430874a9c22b0ce83)):

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE t(x INTEGER[], y INTEGER[]);
```

Populate the  table:

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('{10}',      '{10}'),
('{6}',       '{5,6}'),
('{4,5,6}',   '{5,6}'),
('{5,6}',     '{5,6}'),
('{7,8}',     '{11}'),
('{11}',      '{5,6,7}'),
('{11}',      '{8}'), 
('{9,10}',    '{6}'),

--
-- records below added for testing!
--

('{11}',      '{5,8,10,11,133}'),  
('{9,10}',    '{4,5,6,8,9,10,11}'),
('{9,10}',    '{4,5,6,8,9,10,11}');
```

### Standard ARRAY, UNNEST + EXCEPT ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=767e370843d1676430874a9c22b0ce83)):

If you don't want to, or can't, use [`INTARRAY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/intarray.html).

```
SELECT 
  t.x,
  ARRAY((SELECT UNNEST(t.y)) EXCEPT (SELECT UNNEST(t.x))) 
FROM 
  t;
```

Result:

```
x   array
{10}    {}
{6} {5}
{4,5,6} {}
{5,6}   {}
{7,8}   {11}
{11}    {7,5,6}
{11}    {8}
{9,10}  {6}
{11}    {8,10,133,5}
{9,10}  {11,8,5,4,6}
{9,10}  {11,8,5,4,6}
```

***Et voilà*** - the desired result! See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37917905/how-to-remove-elements-of-array-in-postgresql) for an excellent thread with many approaches to this and closely related issues discussed!

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done like this (all the code below is available on the fiddle  [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9e8f19696d4716c70f37617bf98b7cfd)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_diff (array1 ANYARRAY, array2 ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY 
AS $$

  SELECT COALESCE(ARRAY_AGG(elem), '{}')
  FROM 
    UNNEST(array1) elem
  WHERE elem <> ALL (array2)

$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

and to use it (I put extra records in for testing - check the fiddle):

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) rn,
  x, y,
  array_diff(y, x)
FROM t
ORDER BY rn;
```

Result:

```
rn        x                 y     array_diff
1      {10}              {10}             {}
2       {6}             {5,6}            {5}
3   {4,5,6}             {5,6}             {}
4     {5,6}             {5,6}             {}
5     {7,8}              {11}           {11}
6      {11}           {5,6,7}        {5,6,7}
7      {11}               {8}            {8}
8    {9,10}               {6}            {6}
9      {11}   {5,8,10,11,133}   {5,8,10,133}
10   {9,10} {4,5,6,8,9,10,11}   {4,5,6,8,11}
11   {9,10} {4,5,6,8,9,10,11}   {4,5,6,8,11}
```

See the fiddle for the (trivial) UPDATE.