# SQLAlchemy: Find difference between array columns

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table called `UnitOfWork` which has 3 columns `cases_identified`, `cases_completed` and `cases_double_check`, all of which are Postgresql arrays of integers.

Is it possible to write a query (or a hybrid property) that finds the cases that have been identified, but are not in the completed or double-check columns?

This is what I came up with, but the SQL expression doesn't work:

```
@hybrid_property
def todo(self):
    return [x for x in self.cases_identified
            if x not in self.cases_completed and
            x not in self.cases_double_check]

@todo.expression
def todo(cls):
    return [x for x in cls.cases_identified
            if x not in  cls.cases_completed and
            x not in cls.cases_double_check]
```

The error I get on a test query is:

```
test = Session.query(UnitOfWork.todo).first()
NotImplementedError: Operator 'contains' is not supported on this expression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer I'll assume that `cls.cases_identified`, `cls.cases_completed`, and `cls.cases_double_check` are of `postgresql.ARRAY(Integer)` type in Python side.

Your `@todo.expression` should return just that: an SQL expression. Currently it is trying to return a python list. The exception is raised since a [`postgresql.ARRAY`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) does not support the `in` operator, though it does have a method [`contains`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY.Comparator.contains), which maps to the `@>` operator in Postgresql and tests "if elements are a superset of the elements of the argument array expression". This on the other hand is not what you want. You're lucky that you had the `if x not in ...` in there, as plain

```
[x for x in cls.cases_identified]
```

seems to result in an infinite loop instead of an exception.

Getting the difference between arrays in Postgresql has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533029/how-to-compare-two-arrays-and-pick-only-the-non-matching-elements-in-postgres) extensively, but here's how you would apply that using SQLAlchemy, first using [an array constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
from sqlalchemy import func

...

class UnitOfWork(...):

    @todo.expression
    def todo(cls):
        # Force correlation of `cls` from outer FROM objects. Use
        # the `select()` shorthand method of `FunctionElement`.
        identified = func.unnest(cls.cases_identified).select().correlate(cls)
        completed = func.unnest(cls.cases_completed).select().correlate(cls)
        double_check = func.unnest(cls.cases_double_check).select().correlate(cls)
        # Create the subquery statement
        stmt = identified.except_(completed.union(double_check))
        # Uses the `func` generic for ARRAY constructor from
        # subquery syntax. The subquery statement has to be
        # converted to a "scalar subquery" in the eyes of SQLA
        # (really just a subquery returning 1 col) in order
        # to remove it from the FROM clause hierarchy.
        return func.array(stmt.as_scalar())
```

This has a downside of not providing any FROM objects (as it correlates everything from the enclosing query), so you'd have to issue the original query like this:

```
test = Session.query(UnitOfWork.todo).select_from(UnitOfWork).first()
```

You could also use the Postgresql [intarray module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) that provides special functions and operators for null-free arrays of integers:

```
class UnitOfWork(...):

    @todo.expression
    def todo(cls):
        return (cls.cases_identified - cls.cases_completed - 
                cls.cases_double_check)
```

Note that you have to install the extension first in Postgresql:

```
CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
```