# How to annotate a function element with a FROM object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

While answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269201/sqlalchemy-find-difference-between-array-columns/42341225#42341225) I hit a wall in trying to produce a [hybrid property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) that would return a [function expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html) wrapping a scalar subquery that correlates all its FROM objects from the enclosing query, but it'd still provide a FROM object if no other expression in the enclosing query provides the table to correlate against.

Given a toy model definition

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    foo_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    bar = Column(postgresql.ARRAY(Integer))
    baz = Column(postgresql.ARRAY(Integer))

    @hybrid_property
    def bar_sans_baz(self):
        return list(set(self.bar).difference(self.baz))

    @bar_sans_baz.expression
    def bar_sans_baz(cls):
        bar = func.unnest(cls.bar).select().correlate(cls)
        baz = func.unnest(cls.baz).select().correlate(cls)
        stmt = bar.except_(baz)
        # Uses `func` generic as ARRAY() constructor
        return func.array(stmt.as_scalar(),
                          type_=postgresql.ARRAY(Integer))
```

the problem is that

```
session.query(Foo.bar_sans_baz)
```

results in

```
SELECT array((SELECT unnest(foo.bar) AS unnest_1 
              FROM foo EXCEPT SELECT unnest(foo.baz) AS unnest_2 
              FROM foo)) AS bar_sans_baz
```

since it has nothing to correlate against in the enclosing query. A simple remedy is to use [`select_from()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from) to explicitly add the FROM object:

```
session.query(Foo.bar_sans_baz).select_from(Foo)
```

and the resulting query is the desired

```
SELECT array((SELECT unnest(foo.bar) AS unnest_1
              EXCEPT SELECT unnest(foo.baz) AS unnest_2)) AS bar_sans_baz 
FROM foo
```

While this works, it adds mental overhead as you have to remember to add the `select_from(Foo)`, if only selecting the hybrid property. This is not an issue, if any other select item provides *Foo*:

```
In [105]: print(session.query(Foo.bar_sans_baz, Foo.foo_id))
SELECT array((SELECT unnest(foo.bar) AS unnest_1 EXCEPT SELECT unnest(foo.baz) AS unnest_2)) AS bar_sans_baz, foo.foo_id AS foo_foo_id 
FROM foo
```

Is there a way to annotate the returned function expression `func.array(...)` – or the inner scalar subquery – so that it will provide *Foo* as the FROM object, if no other expression provides it. Or in other words, just a way to add *Foo* as `from_obj` to the function expression or the scalar subquery so that the inner selects can use that.

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you won't add `.select_from` explicitly in the `expression` definition:

```
@bar_sans_baz.expression
def bar_sans_baz(cls):
    bar = func.unnest(cls.bar).select().correlate(cls)
    baz = func.unnest(cls.baz).select().correlate(cls)
    stmt = bar.except_(baz).select_from(cls.__tablename__)
    # Uses `func` generic as ARRAY() constructor
    return func.array(stmt.as_scalar(),
                      type_=postgresql.ARRAY(Integer))
```

Comment: It's a good idea, though a `CompoundSelect` such as produced by `except_()` does not have the method `select_from()`. I'm also not entirely sure how it'd play out, if you add "select from" to the statement that will then be marked scalar subquery and wrapped in `ARRAY()` constructor.

Comment: In case the previous comment wasn't clear (it got a bit lengthy), this does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was not sure it would 100% work. Maybe you could try to improve my answer?