# Sqlalchemy: filter operation using two ARRAY type columns

Tags: python, arrays, sqlalchemy

I have two classes: Question and User. The Question class has a field called `category_ids` of type `Column(ARRAY(Integer))`, while the User class has an object, `preferences`, which has a field called `ignored_categories`, also of type `Column(ARRAY(Integer))`.

I am trying to query all the questions that don't have at least one value in the `category_ids` field that appears in the `ignored_categories` field from user's preferences OR if the previous is true, have any other value in the `category_ids` field that is not in the user's preferences field `ignore_categories`. As such, the following should be true:

- `category_ids`=[] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should pass.
- `category_ids`=[1, 2, 4] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should pass.
- `category_ids`=[1] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should ignore.
- `category_ids`=[1, 2, 3] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should ignore.
- `category_ids`=[1, 2, 3, 4] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should pass.
- `category_ids`=[5, 7] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should pass.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
user = DBSession.query(User).filter_by(id=user_id).one() # this gets the user object
query = DBSession.query(Question).order_by(Question.created_at.desc())
query = query.filter(
    or_(
        not_(
            Question.category_ids.overlap(user.preferences.ignored_categories)
        ),
        Question.category_ids.contains(user.preferences.ignored_categories)
    )
)
```

The problem with this is that `contains` only tests if the `category_ids` is a superset of `ignored_categories`, this failing to give the correct result for data sets such as:

- `category_ids`=[1] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should ignore.

Thus, it needs another condition which tests if there is at least one value that matches, and no other that doesn't.

The `overlap` function only tests if there is at least one value present in both arrays, but this fails tests such as:

- `category_ids`=[1, 2, 4] and `ignored_categories`=[1, 2, 3] => should pass.

Which should pass, but it doesn't, since I need to negate the operation. If I don't negate it, it'd only filter for arrays which have absolutely nothing in common.

EDIT: this is how my tables looks like:

```
class User(Base, DictSerializable):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = dict(schema='user')

    id = Column(types.Id, primary_key=True)
    # other fields


class UserPreferences(Base, DictSerializable):
    __tablename__ = 'user_preferences'
    __table_args__ = dict(schema='user')

    id = Column(types.Id, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(types.Id, ForeignKey(User.id))
    ignored_categories = Column(types.ARRAY(types.Number), default=[])
    # other fields

    user = relationship("User",
                        backref=backref("preferences", single_parent=True, cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                                        passive_deletes=True, uselist=False),
                        )

class Question(Base, DictSerializable):
    __tablename__ = 'questions'
    __table_args__ = dict(schema='question')

    id = Column(types.Id, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(types.Id, ForeignKey(User.id, ondelete="CASCADE", onupdate="CASCADE"))

    # other fields

    category_ids = Column(types.ARRAY(types.Integer))

    user = relationship("User", foreign_keys=user_id,
                        backref=backref("questions", order_by=id, single_parent=True, uselist=True,
                                        cascade="all, delete-orphan", passive_deletes=True)
                        )


question_categories = Table('question_categories', Base.metadata, 
    Column('question_id', types.Integer, ForeignKey(Question.id)), 
    Column('category_id', types.Integer, ForeignKey(Category.id)) )
Question.categories = relationship(Category, secondary=question_categories, backref=backref('questions'))
```

Comment: What you need is the set difference operation. You cannot emulate set difference with intersection ("overlap") and subset ("contains"). How you accomplish set difference depends on your database. For this reason, arrays are usually considered less flexible than join tables.

Comment: @univerio I have updated the question with the tables structure. Could you recommend me they way I should do it with a join quiery?

Comment: By "join table" I mean `CREATE TABLE question_categories (question_id int, category_id int, PRIMARY KEY (question_id, category_id)`. For your specific situation you might be able to get away with `ignored_categories.contains(category_ids)`, accounting for the case where `category_ids` is empty.

Comment: What DB are you using? I'd suspect Postgresql from using schemas and ARRAYs, and if so, [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269201/sqlalchemy-find-difference-between-array-columns/42341225#42341225).

Comment: @univerio Such a table already exists. I have updated the question with it (`question_categories`). I needed the `category_ids` column for a faster accessibility to the categories, without having to send all of them as an array of objects. But I still fail to see how I could use that table to filter the questions like I want to.

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes, I am using PostgreSQL and I have already reached that post, but I don't understand how I could use it. :) I don't want to make an expression on the `Question` class, but instead just filter a query.

Answer (score 0):

This problem amounts to finding an element in `category_ids` that does not exist in `ignored_categories`, with the special case where if `category_ids` is empty it is not ignored.

This can be accomplished with join tables as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT questions.*
FROM questions
LEFT JOIN question_categories ON questions.id = question_categories.question_id
WHERE (
  question_categories.category_id IS NULL  -- special case where question has no categories
  OR question_categories.category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT category_id FROM user_ignored_categories WHERE user_id = 123  -- for this user
  )  -- find a category that isn't ignored
)
```

To do this with arrays, you can do this:

```
SELECT questions.*
FROM questions
WHERE (
  cardinality(categories) = 0  -- special case where question has no categories
  OR NOT ((SELECT ignored_categories FROM users WHERE id = 123) @> categories)
);
```

You can test these against your data [here](http://rextester.com/EPKP92998).