# Postgres where clause when using subqueries in update

Tags: postgresql

The queries of this question are here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/16abc/5

I have this table `person` which has two columns, id and age. When I run an update statement

```
update person
set age = ((select person.age) + 1)
where person.id = 1;
```

The age is set using the subquery`((select person.age) + 1`.

What are the constraints which are applied on this select expression? Does it inherit the where clause of the update statement, retrieving the age of the row with person.id = 1?

From testing against some data it does appear that this is the case.

In this specific case the age can be set directly without resorting to a sub-select, but I was looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535089/1089912 and wondered if these select expressions when used in an update statement, inherit the constraints of the surrounding update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "subquery" `(select person.age)` is identical to the column reference `person.age` or just `age` without the `select` because it does not have a `from` clause.

You can [see](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=05dfb0ae8a8ac3c561130ffe265b8a5d) the effect of the "subquery", when you use it in a SELECT statement's column list:

```
select id, (select person.age) as age
from person
where id = 1;
```

So your UPDATE is 100% identical to:

```
update person
  set age = age + 1
where id = 1;
```

Comment: Is this a general rule, that these expressions without a where clause are treated the same as column references? When I wrote the question I was trying to provide a minimal working example for a more complex scenario, such as `SET names = array(SELECT unnest(names) EXCEPT ... )` related to arrayfields in postgres.

Comment: They are only treated the same if the SELECT is a scalar query, i.e. returns a single value